# Lock Screen MacBook Pro 2015

Tags: macbook-pro

How Can I Lock my MacBook Pro 2015 screen?

In MacBook Pro 2014 it works with <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>, but it doesn't work in MacBook Pro 2015.

Comment: Have you seen the "Lock Screen" shortcut under Apple menu?

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?  Also, there's no pre-defined `Control-Command-Q` to "lock" your screen.  Was it something that was user defined?

Comment: Well Control-Command-Q stils works in High Sierra on my Mac, I haven't changed any configuration for this.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple () menu provides a way for you to lock your MacBook’s screen.

Answer (score 1):

Use Control-Shift-Power to lock your MacBook. (For older MacBooks with an optical drive, use Control-Shift-Eject.)
Use Command-Option-Power to put your MacBook to sleep. (For older MacBooks with an optical drive, use Command-Option-Eject.)
Hope it helps you out. Cheers.